# Adding an autofill option in Google Sheets according to data

Tags: validation, google-sheets, automation, autofill

I want to make a spreadsheet with details of the schools and students in the area.

I have created an [example Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d-6pnK52MO-YRvuFBTpS4-r_rA3HjD7ePd3jqi7v0N0/edit?usp=sharing).

I want the help of you amazing guys to add an automation.

This spreadsheet consists of 2 sheets:

1. the details about the student's school
2. details about the school

Details about the school are pre entered (there are only a limited number of schools and the details about the school (the area, contact number) are unique.

When I select the school in sheet 1, I want to automatically fill column C and D.

When I select a school from the data validation in Sheet 1, column B, I want column C and column D to autofill from the data in sheet 2.

For example For Ming Coltrane (A2), if I select the school (B2) as Big valley High... I want automation to look at the details about Big valley High in sheet 2 and fill the area and contact number accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below formula in cell **C2**:

```
=IFERROR(Arrayformula(VLOOKUP(B2:B,{'Sheet 2'!A2:C,'Sheet 2'!A2:C},{2,3},0)),"")
```

[image]

#### Reference:

- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very much your idea worked very well for my need, thanks for the support